# Complex numbers series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, power-series, divergent-series

Does there exist a complex numbers serie $a_n$ (n is natural number) that $\sum_{n=1}^
∞ a_nz^n$ converge when $z=1+i$ and $z=100+40i$
and diverge when $z = 40+80i$ . Any ideas how to show this?

Comment: The power series will have a *radius of convergence* about the origin.  Is this concept familiar to you?  It is often covered in first year calculus classes.

Answer (score 2):

No, because if a power series centered at $0$ converges at $100+40i$ then it also converges at any $z\in\mathbb C$ such that $|z|<|100+40i|$. And $|40+80i|<|100+40i|$.